# Use PDF form button to screenshot form and attach it in outlook

Tags: javascript, pdf

what I currently have in place is a button that when clicked, sends the full form via email. The recipient of the pdf can then modify the form. I do not want that. I don't want him to be able to edit the fields afterwards. Do I need JavaSript?

Comment: @KJ Thank you for your answer. The "Form" I did was pretty basic.. I just added some boxes in a PDF page and I got myself a "form"...

Answer (score 0):

## Probably not.

You need to send a different PDF that isn't editable.

If you are generating the PDF using Javascript, then you should consult the docs for your library to see how to remove editable fields.

But if you created the PDF in a more traditional way, such as authoring it in a word processor and then exporting it as a PDF, then you'll need to create a second PDF that doesn't have editable fields.

It sounds like you want to send the person a "finalized" version of the form; this probably means you need to generate this second PDF on demand. That code usually lives on the web server (or in the cloud), and would be written in whatever languages your server supports. If your server is running Node, then you actually *would* do this with Javascript.

But if it's any other language (I've done this with PHP), you would do the work in that language and then respond with the just-generated PDF, which your web-based JS would then download.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I'm generating the PDF using Adobe Acrobat app. How can I then send the form but in a non editable form? Isnt there something in adobe? I can'T believe I need to write code for that...

Comment: You'll have to do some research, but I think that means this question is not a javascript question. You may need to study and solve several smaller problems to sort this out.